# Layout problems?

Tags: android, android-imageview

So the error occurred when I changed all the imageView IDs. I am absolutely lost on how to solve this error. Should I just start over?? The errors are

-Error:(83) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_scaleType' in package 'android'

-Error:(126) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_scalelType' in package 'android'

-Error:(128, 39) String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_constraint').

-Error:(129, 40) String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_constraint').

- Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /Users/jfenriqu/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/jfenriqu/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar -M /Volumes/TEALSTICK/CapstoneV5/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Volumes/TEALSTICK/CapstoneV5/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug -m -J /Volumes/TEALSTICK/CapstoneV5/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Volumes/TEALSTICK/CapstoneV5/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.example.jfenriqu.capstonev5 -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Volumes/TEALSTICK/CapstoneV5/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug --no-version-vectors}
- Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process /Users/jfenriqu/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/jfenriqu/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar -M /Volumes/TEALSTICK/CapstoneV5/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Volumes/TEALSTICK/CapstoneV5/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug -m -J /Volumes/TEALSTICK/CapstoneV5/app/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Volumes/TEALSTICK/CapstoneV5/app/build/intermediates/res/debug/resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.example.jfenriqu.capstonev5 -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Volumes/TEALSTICK/CapstoneV5/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug --no-version-vectors}
- Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/jfenriqu/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

  ```
  <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

      <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/zeldaView"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gumballView"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mortalView"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/zelda" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/smashView"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="149dp"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/gumballView"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MariokartView"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/smash" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/playstationView"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="221dp"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dragonballView"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/haloView"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/playstation" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/mortalView"
              android:layout_width="192dp"
              android:layout_height="210dp"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/smashView"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/mortalkombat" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/MariokartView"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/falloutView"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/mariokart" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/gumballView"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mortalView"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mortalView"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/smashView"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/gumball" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageView13"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/gameofthrones" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageView12"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/zeldaView"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/zeldaView"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gumballView"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/familyguy" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/falloutView"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="171dp"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/darksoulsView"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/fallout" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/darksoulsView"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/playstationView"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/playstationView"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dragonballView"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/darksouls" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/crashView"
              android:layout_width="match_constraint"
              android:layout_height="match_constraint"
              android:layout_scalelType="fitXY"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gumballView"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/smashView"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/smashView"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/crashbandicoot" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/dragonballView"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/haloView"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/haloView"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/haloView"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/dragonball" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/haloView"
              android:layout_width="192dp"
              android:layout_height="258dp"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
              app:srcCompat="@drawable/halo" />

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/imageView"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:scaleType="fitXY"
              android:src="@drawable/gameofthrones"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/zeldaView" />
      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

  </ScrollView>
  ```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Try to rebuild your project and also sync your gradle

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig Thanks but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: okay change something in gradle and then sync project

Comment: if that even not worked then try to invalidate and restart android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -Error:(83) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_scaleType' in 
>      package 'android'
>
> -Error:(126) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_scalelType' in >package 'android'
>
> -Error:(128, 39) String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value >'match_constraint').
>
> -Error:(129, 40) String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_constraint').

Theses are all typos, 
replace **layout_scaleType** and **layout_scalelType** with **scaleType** and **match_constraint** with **0dp**

To make a view match_constraint in constraint layout we use 0dp

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't solve the errors.

Comment: @JoseEnriquez Updated my answer

Comment: This did help with the constraint errors. But the resource identifier errors are still there with 'scale_type' instead. Thanks for the constraint tip.

Comment: @JoseEnriquez Sorry, I meant **scaleType** not **scale_type**, answer    updated